# How to round to nearest multiple?

Tags: julia

Is there an idiomatic way to round to the nearest multiple of a number?

```
number   multiple    result
12.2       0.5        12.0
12.2       0.25       12.25
12.4       0.5        12.5
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define a function:

```
round_step(x, step) = round(x / step) * step
```

Usage:

```
julia> round_step(12.2, 0.25)
12.25
```

Such a function is actually used internally in Base for rounding numbers to a certain number of digits in a certain base:

```
julia> Base._round_step(12.2, 0.25, RoundNearest)
12.25
```

However since this is an internal implementation detail you shouldn't rely on this function. This function in turn calls `_round_invstep`.

```
julia> Base._round_invstep(12.2, 4, RoundNearest)
12.25

julia> Base._round_invstep(12.4, 2, RoundNearest)
12.5
```

Which performs the operation `round(x * invstep, r) / invstep`.

Because your examples happen to correspond to 0.1 in base 4 and base 2 you can also use `round` directly for these particular cases:

```
julia> round(12.2; base=2, digits=1)
12.0

julia> round(12.2; base=4, digits=1)
12.25

julia> round(12.4; base=2, digits=1)
12.5
```